# Probability: Trains running on schedule

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

When travelling normally to university you have noticed that the train which you catch in the morning runs to schedule only about $60\%$ of the time. Assuming this to be correct and that trains run on schedule or not independently on different days, calculate the probability that out of $5$ mornings when you take the train,

(i) $3$ trains are on time,
(ii) at least $2$ trains are on time, and
(iii) the probability that the third train is the first one to be on time.

Comment: Do you know the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?...and what have You tried?

Comment: i know binomial distn but i cant caught the logic of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) This is just $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 0.6^3\cdot 0.4^2\approx 0.3457$, since we have $3$ successes with probability $0.6$, two fails with probability $0.4$, and $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to order them.

ii) Count probability that 0 or 1 trains are on time. Probability of $1$ is $5\cdot 0.6^1\cdot 0.4^4 \approx 0.0768$. Similarly, probability of $0$ is $0.4^5 \approx 0.0102$. Adding them and subtracting from 1 gets us $0.913$ for ii (complementary probability).

iii) We need first and second to be late, then third to be on time. After that it doesn't matter what else happens, so it's just $0.4\cdot 0.4\cdot 0.6 \approx 0.096$.

-FruDe

Answer (score 1):

> i know binomial distn but i cant caught the logic of the question

for example, question (i) asks you to calculate the probability to have 3 successes on 5 independent trials, that means

$$\binom{5}{3}0.6^3\cdot 0.4^2$$

and so on...

Comment: Thank you. but in (iii) the probability that the third train is the first one to be on time. what will be the value of n and r

Comment: @MdShakilSikder : think a little bit....they ask you to calculate the probability that the third train is the first one to be on time....say this in a different way "the first and the second train to be not in time and the third to be on time....$0.4\times0.4\times0.6$